# How can I add html with helpers and expressions as an attribute to my partial?

Tags: templates, handlebars.js

I have a partial and I need to swap out a link depending on the context, and I also need to use helpers on my expressions within that link. I tried adding this to my partial and including it in the partial template, but it is adding the line as a string, instead of html.

```
{{> partial link='<a href="/matchup/{{formatForWeb this.name }}/{{formatForWeb 
matchup.name }}" class="matchup-card__link">code</a>'}}
```

I then added it as {{link}} to my partial template:

```
<div>
     {{link}}
</div>
```

Here it is in dev tools being added as a string to my page:

[image]

How can I make this work? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use a `helper` inside a `partial`.

The solution is to pass the data and HTML elements in different variables to the partial and do the manipulation within the partial definition.

Example

```
{{> newPartial 
  link = '<a href="/matchup/temp1/temp2" class="matchup-card__link">code</a>'
  var1 = this.name 
  var2 = matchup.name
}}
```

Note that as per the syntax, the data(var1 and var2) should not be wrapped inside curly braces`{{}}` or quotes`""`.

Now the partial can be registered as below

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('newPartial', function(val) {
  console.log(val);
  return val;
});
```

Here, in the variable `val`, you will receive all the 3 variables `link`, `var1` and `var2` as array objects, with which you may handle the manipulation and `return` the end result.

Hope this helps.